# Unable to create an IBM Container Instance

Tags: ibm-cloud

When trying to perform any action related to IBM Containers I get the following "**Catalog Error**"...

**BXNUI0115E**: The attempt to retrieve containers failed because a problem occurred contacting IBM Containers. Try again later. If the problem continues, go to Support. For other help options, see the Bluemix Docs.

Help,
Francisco

Answer (score 1):

there has been a maintenance activity planned for Sep 9 at 5:00 AM US Eastern time, so probably your problem could be related to this activity.
Moreover actually there is an alert about Container environment raised on Sep 10, 2015 2:00 AM UTC+02

> Issues with Containers in US-SOUTH region IBM Containers in the
>   US-SOUTH region are experiencing issues. Users will be unable to
>   connect and perform most operations. Under investigation.

We expect this issue will be fixed in few hours.

You can have updates about Bluemix status and activity alerts on this page
https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#status